# How to get two RichText features to be mutually exclusive

Tags: python, django, wagtail, draftail

So basically I've added two custom features for coloring text to a RichTextBlock, and I'd like to make them so selecting one for a portion of text would automatically unselect the other color button, much like it's already the case for h tags.

I've searched for a bit but didn't find much, so I guess I could use some help, be it advice, instruction or even code.

My features go like this :

```
@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_redtext_feature(features):
    feature_name = 'redtext'
    type_ = 'RED_TEXT'
    tag = 'span'

    control = {
        'type': type_,
        'label': 'Red',
        'style': {'color': '#bd003f'},
    }

    features.register_editor_plugin(
        'draftail', feature_name, draftail_features.InlineStyleFeature(control)
    )

    db_conversion = {
        'from_database_format': {tag: InlineStyleElementHandler(type_)},
        'to_database_format': {
            'style_map': {
                type_: {'element': tag, 'props': {'class': 'text-primary'}}
            }
        },
    }

    features.register_converter_rule(
        'contentstate', feature_name, db_conversion
    )
```

The other one is similar but color is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but it requires jumping through many hoops in Wagtail. The `h1…h6` tags work like this out of the box because they are block-level formatting – each block within the editor can only be of one type. Here you’re creating this `RED_TEXT` formatting as inline formatting ("inline style"), which, intentionally supports multiple formats being applied to the same text.

---

If you want to achieve this mutually exclusive implementation anyway – you’ll need to write custom JS code to auto-magically remove the desired styles from the text when attempting to add a new style.

Here is a function that does just that. It goes through all of the characters in the user’s selection, and removes the relevant styles from them:

```js
/**
 * Remove all of the COLOR_ styles from the current selection.
 * This is to ensure only one COLOR_ style is applied per range of text.
 * Replicated from https://github.com/thibaudcolas/draftjs-filters/blob/f997416a0c076eb6e850f13addcdebb5e52898e5/src/lib/filters/styles.js#L7,
 * with additional "is the character in the selection" logic.
 */
export const filterColorStylesFromSelection = (
  content: ContentState,
  selection: SelectionState,
) => {
  const blockMap = content.getBlockMap();
  const startKey = selection.getStartKey();
  const endKey = selection.getEndKey();
  const startOffset = selection.getStartOffset();
  const endOffset = selection.getEndOffset();

  let isAfterStartKey = false;
  let isAfterEndKey = false;

  const blocks = blockMap.map((block) => {
    const isStartBlock = block.getKey() === startKey;
    const isEndBlock = block.getKey() === endKey;
    isAfterStartKey = isAfterStartKey || isStartBlock;
    isAfterEndKey = isAfterEndKey || isEndBlock;
    const isBeforeEndKey = isEndBlock || !isAfterEndKey;
    const isBlockInSelection = isAfterStartKey && isBeforeEndKey;

    // Skip filtering through the block chars if out of selection.
    if (!isBlockInSelection) {
      return block;
    }

    let altered = false;

    const chars = block.getCharacterList().map((char, i) => {
      const isAfterStartOffset = i >= startOffset;
      const isBeforeEndOffset = i < endOffset;
      const isCharInSelection =
        // If the selection is on a single block, the char needs to be in-between start and end offsets.
        (isStartBlock &&
          isEndBlock &&
          isAfterStartOffset &&
          isBeforeEndOffset) ||
        // Start block only: after start offset
        (isStartBlock && !isEndBlock && isAfterStartOffset) ||
        // End block only: before end offset.
        (isEndBlock && !isStartBlock && isBeforeEndOffset) ||
        // Neither start nor end: just "in selection".
        (isBlockInSelection && !isStartBlock && !isEndBlock);

      let newChar = char;

      if (isCharInSelection) {
        char
          .getStyle()
          .filter((type) => type.startsWith("COLOR_"))
          .forEach((type) => {
            altered = true;
            newChar = CharacterMetadata.removeStyle(newChar, type);
          });
      }

      return newChar;
    });

    return altered ? block.set("characterList", chars) : block;
  });

  return content.merge({
    blockMap: blockMap.merge(blocks),
  });
};
```

This is taken from the Draftail [ColorPicker](https://github.com/springload/draftail/blob/main/examples/components/ColorPicker.js) demo, which you can see running in the [Draftail Storybook’s "Custom formats" example](https://demo.draftail.org/storybook/?path=/story/examples--custom-formats).

---

To implement this kind of customisation in Draftail, you’d need to use the [controls](https://www.draftail.org/docs/arbitrary-controls) API. Unfortunately that API isn’t currently supported out of the box in Wagtail’s integration of the editor (see [wagtail/wagtail#5580](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/5580)), so at the moment in order for this to work you’d need to customize Draftail’s initialisation within Wagtail as well.